Is there anyway to use padding_mode='circular' in nn.ConvTranspose2d?
I'm a beginner of DCGAN with Pytorch. I found that nn.ConvTranspose2d did not support padding_mode='circular' even in 2024. However, nn.Conv2d supports circular padding mode and works well.
nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 16, 4, 1, 0, bias=False, padding_mode='circular') 

The error is shown as follows,
ValueError: Only "zeros" padding mode is supported for ConvTranspose2d

Is there any way to use circular padding mode in nn.ConvTranspose2d?

Padding in a transpose convolution is used to make the intermediate grid before passing over the transpose convolution kernel. It doesn't make sense to use non-zero padding in that scenario.

@Karl, thanks for your quick reply. In fact I'm following one literature, see Fig. A1 in link. This author stated that the circular padding is utilized in Conv2d and ConvTranspose2d , though he used tensorflow not pytorch. Fig. A1 also showed that the zero padding and circular padding were not identital even in ConvTranspose2d. You said it was nonsense. Which one is correct?

The paper you cited does indeed use circular padding for transpose convolution, no doubt here. If you want to replicate this, maybe you can try using torch.nn.functional.pad before the ConvTranspose ? This function accepts 'circular' as an argument

@trialNerror.Thanks for your clarification. I think 'torch.nn.functional.pad' will work well with padding values outside matrix, but not fully satisfy my requirement. For example, while upscaling a tensor 44 to 88 (batch_size and feature map are neglected) with kernel size=44, stride=2,padding =1, 'F.pad(image, pad=(2, 2, 2, 2), mode='circular')' should work well with padding values outside 44.  However, padding values inside 44 also need to be determined, only both padding values could fully construct a 1111 matrix for latter convolution. But I could not find corresponding measure.

The paper you linked is using a different definition of padding for the transpose convolution. The padding referenced by pytorch refers to padding the intermediate grid - you can see a visual example here. The paper applies circular padding only to the outside of the tensor prior to the transpose convolution. You can get the same effect by applying circular padding in a separate step before the transpose convolution

@Karl. Thanks for your further explanation. I have contacted with the author, they have provided original sources in link, I see they used this code for circular padding
def pad_dim(x, n=1):     x = tf.concat((x[:,:,-n:,:], x, x[:,:,:n,:]), axis=-2)     x = tf.concat((x[:,-n:,:,:], x, x[:,:n,:,:]), axis=1)     return x. Maybe this code clarified their measure. Is there equivalent code in Pytorch could do the same operation?

@Karl. I finally figure out that the author also used def delete_dim(x):     x = x[:, 3:-3, 3:-3, :]     return x, which could delete the extra arrays caused by circular padding. Yes, this author use a circular padding, but only outside the original matrix.

You can use nn.CircularPad2d to apply the padding to the outside of the matrix
